# Could pypy speed up parts of my python code?

Tags: python

I need pypy to speed up my python code. While the pypy doesn't support a lot of modules I need (e.g. GNU Radio). Could I use pypy to speed up parts of my python code. Could I use pypy to only speed up some of my python files? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You can only have one interpreter instance running all of the code in a single program at a time. The exception is if you break out some of your functionality into a totally separate program that communicates with the other part of your code through some form of inter-process communication; then you can run those totally separate programs however you like. But for code that is not separated like that, it's not possible.

It will probably be more straightforward to adapt the entirety of your code to work with PyPy one way or another, instead of trying to break out bits and pieces. If that's absolutely not possible, then PyPy probably can't help you.

Comment: Another way to break things up (specifically for GNURADIO) is to stream things around with UDP

Comment: @portforwardpodcast: you mean and then to process things on another PC?

Comment: @portforwardpodcast: ping?

Comment: Yeah run them on another pc or run them on multiple threads depending on your workload.  Your original question wasn't very clear as to your workload.  What computer are you using? What sort of data crunching are you doing?  Are you able to break your workload into threads?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. And GNU Radio does the signal processing and scheduling in C++, so that's totally opaque to your python interpreter. Also, GNU Radio itself is highly optimized and contains specialized implementations for most of the CPU intense tasks for SSE, SSE4, and some NEON.

> I need pypy to speed up my python code.

I doubt that. If your program runs too slow, it's probably nothing your Python interpreter can solve -- you might have to look into what could take so much time, and solve this on a higher level.